# from vs fromUnfiltered with nullable variable - Optaplanner

Tags: java, quarkus, optaplanner

I need clarification about the behaviour of `from` and `fromUnfiltered` when using `planningEntities` with `nullable` variables in Optaplanner.

The [user documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.12.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constraintStreamsFrom) states that

> The .from(T) building block selects every T instance that is in a problem fact collection or a planning entity collection and has no null planning variables.

> To include instances with a null planning variable, especially if you use nullable variables, replace the from() building block by fromUnfiltered():

But the [java doc](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.12.0.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/stream/ConstraintFactory.html#from(java.lang.Class)) of `from` methods states that `from` method will filter entities with null variables except if it's a `nullable` variable:

> Start a ConstraintStream of all instances of the fromClass that are known as problem facts or planning entities.

> If the fromClass is a PlanningEntity, then it will be automatically filtered to only contain fully initialized entities, for which each genuine PlanningVariable (of the fromClass or a superclass thereof) is initialized (**so when the value is not null - unless PlanningVariable.nullable() is modified**). This filtering will NOT automatically apply to genuine planning variables of subclass planning entities of the fromClass.

I'm not sure if my understanding is correct, and my tests show that javadoc is correct, and user documentation is misleading. Or perhaps I'm missing the point.

Anyone to clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This whole situation with `from(...)` has been painful for a while. The behavior in OptaPlanner 8.13.0.Final and older is as follows:

- For entities with `nullable = false` planning variables (the default), `from(...)` returns only the entities that don't have `null` in any of their genuine planning variables.
- For entities with `nullable = true` planning variables (overconstrained planning), `from(...)` still returns entities with `null` in any of their genuine planning variables after these entities are intialized. In other words - it will not return them during construction heuristics, but it will return them in subsequent local search, if the construction heuristic has decided to *keep* the `null` there.

However, this is not the only confusing behavior when it comes to `null` handling. With conditional propagation (`ifExists(...)` etc.), we will *always* return entities with `null` genuine variables, in every situation.

We have recently realized that this situation is not sustainable and, starting with OptaPlanner 8.14.0.Final (to be released soon), we have deprecated `from(...)` and introduced `forEach(...)`, which cleans up all this mess. From this version on, when using the new API, the behavior regarding `null` variables will be clearer and, more importantly, consistent.

`forEach(...)` will *never* return entities with `null` variables, `forEachIncludingNullVars(...)` should be used for that. And conditional propagation will honor that, too.

See [upgrade recipe](https://www.optaplanner.org/download/upgradeRecipe/upgradeRecipe8.html) when the new version is out.

Comment: thanks for your cristal clear answer!
Indeed I have experienced some troubles with `IfExists`...

Would you advice me to migrate right now to 8.14.0-SNAPSHOT (I'm currently on 8.12.0.Final) ? My project won't go live before a few weeks, maybe months. Will the 8.14 be released by then?
Thanks

Comment: 8.14.0.Final should be out in a few weeks, although we never make promises on community GA dates. In the meantime, you can build OptaPlanner from source - it's not too hard, only takes a few minutes. Alternatively, add the JBoss snapshot repo (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/) to your project. Obviously, be careful - SNAPSHOTs are the opposite of stable.

Comment: Yes I imagine that SNAPSHOT is not stable, but my project is not stable either ;)
I'll give it a try. Thanks for your time